# How to specify path for base image for kaniko?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab-ci, kaniko

I want to build image using base image files behind firewall. I have no experience with kaniko and not found suitable explanation in internet.

For example I can send an image file (i.e. ubuntu + tools) to the secure network behind a firewall but I can not use a proxy since it is not working because of toxic restrictions (for example I can not download security updates to make it secure).

How I can call kaniko to use this base image during building image using Dockerfile - let assume that this files will somewhere on file system - I want for example deploy custom Python application using standard image + my source code and some configuration.

Let assume such simple build (I can write hundred lines but problem is how to specify path to base image in kaniko - no matter). My base image `python` will be in secure network visible to kaniko.

```
FROM python
CMD ['sleep', 'inf']
```

Answer (score 0):

[There are several ways of building containers using Kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko#tutorial). But in general you can basically use that same Dockerfile you provided and one example would to run kaniko from the command line like this:

```
echo -e 'FROM python \nCMD ["sleep", "inf"' > Dockerfile | tar -cf - Dockerfile | gzip -9 | docker run \
  --interactive -v $(pwd):/workspace gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest \
  --context tar://stdin \
  --destination=<the host of your container registry>/your_image:your_tag
```

Comment: I think this is not solution problem because you can not write/use "FROM python" because there not access to `python` image in this network so I need to copy `python` image first then I need to use kaniko to use this image - for example pointing folder or image.

Comment: Yes, depending on the your network setup you may or may not have access to the public images. You have to substitute with the container image that you have access to.

Comment: Let assume that I have no public image access - I can only put images on file system only. Is it possible to build image with kaniko with such setup. I trying to find solution but it looks it is impossible.